# Open VPN troubleshooting

Tags: vpn, openvpn, troubleshooting

I'm trying to set up a site-to-site VPN connection between 2 of our offices.
The VPN servers i'm using are 2 "Edgerouter lite" and the tunneling software i'm using is OpenVPN.

This is how the setup is at the moment:

-

```
R1:
LAN subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
LAN port: 192.168.2.1

WAN port: X.X.X.X
```

-

```
R2:
LAN subnet: 10.10.0.0/24
LAN port: 10.10.0.34

WAN port: Y.Y.Y.Y
```

-

```
R1 Open VPN config:
 openvpn vtun0 {
     local-address 192.168.2.1 {
     }
     local-port 1194
     mode site-to-site
     openvpn-option --comp-lzo
     openvpn-option --float
     openvpn-option "--ping 10"
     openvpn-option "--ping-restart 20"
     openvpn-option --ping-timer-rem
     openvpn-option --persist-tun
     openvpn-option --persist-key
     openvpn-option "--user nobody"
     openvpn-option "--group nogroup"
     remote-address 10.10.0.39
     remote-host X.X.X.X
     remote-port 1194
     shared-secret-key-file /config/auth/secret
 }
```

-

```
R2 Open VPN config:
 openvpn vtun0 {
     local-address 10.10.0.39 {
     }
     local-port 1194
     mode site-to-site
     openvpn-option --comp-lzo
     openvpn-option --float
     openvpn-option "--ping 10"
     openvpn-option "--ping-restart 20"
     openvpn-option --ping-timer-rem
     openvpn-option --persist-tun
     openvpn-option --persist-key
     openvpn-option "--user nobody"
     openvpn-option "--group nogroup"
     remote-address 192.168.2.1
     remote-host Y.Y.Y.Y
     remote-port 1194
     shared-secret-key-file /config/auth/secret
 }
```

-

```
show openvpn status site-to-site on R1

OpenVPN client status on vtun0 []

Remote CN       Remote IP       Tunnel IP       TX byte RX byte Connected Since
--------------- --------------- --------------- ------- ------- ------------------------
None (PSK)      Y.Y.Y.Y   10.10.0.39        51.6K   51.0K N/A
```

-

```
show openvpn status site-to-site on R2

OpenVPN client status on vtun0 []

Remote CN       Remote IP       Tunnel IP       TX byte RX byte Connected Since
--------------- --------------- --------------- ------- ------- ------------------------
None (PSK)      X.X.X.X   192.168.2.1       85.3K   84.5K N/A
```

-

```
Routing table R1:
IP              Next hop    INT     TYPE
0.0.0.0/0       X.X.X.XGW   eth1    static
127.0.0.0/8                 lo      connected
192.168.2.0/24              eth0    connected
X.X.X.X/X                   eth1    connected
10.10.0.0/24                vtun0   static
10.10.0.39/32               vtun0   connected
```

-

```
Routing table R2:
IP              Next hop    INT     TYPE
0.0.0.0/0       Y.Y.Y.YGW   eth0    static
127.0.0.0/8                 lo      connected
10.10.0.0/24                eth1    connected
Y.Y.Y.Y/Y                   eth0    connected   
192.168.2.0/24              vtun0   static
192.168.2.1/32              vtun0   connected
```

From a host on the 192.168.2.0 LAN (On R1) i can ping 10.10.0.34 (LAN port IP on R2) but i can't ping 10.10.0.4 (a host on the R2 LAN).

Is there anything wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This usually has to do with routing. If you can get from one OpenVPN endpoint to the other, you should be pretty close to a working setup - but:

- Make sure IP forwarding is enabled if there is a LAN that needs to be accessible beyond a particular endpoint.
- Clients on the remote side of a connection do not know how to get back to the other side of the connection. This is true both ways through the tunnel.

You can fix this by using the `iroute` and `push` statements in the `openvpn.conf` of your choice. If you are joining two networks `x.x.x.x` and `y.y.y.y`, then on the server side (say `x.x.x.x`), you can do this:

- `push "route net mask"` or `push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"` for instance. This hands the remote clients on `y.y.y.y` the correct route back to `x.x.x.x` through the tunnel.
- If the server side (`x.x.x.x`) needs to be able to see stations beyond the OpenVPN gateway at `y.y.y.y`, you also need to use the `iroute` statement. Put `iroute y.y.y.y 255.255.255.0` on the server side to make this happen. This basically lets OpenVPN know which client is responsible for a particular subnet.

  - `iroute` statements need to go into the `ccd` (Client Config Directory I think). This would usually be in files named `/etc/openvpn/ccd/<client name>`.

This should get you going, I would think. Also, have a look at the excellent OpenVPN documentation - [like this bit on LANs](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans). Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Just to be clear, the x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y addresses you reference is not the public addresses i masked in my op, but rather just example local subnets, right?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Just local subnets.

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so, please feel free to vote up my answer :-)